# Using DataTables to merge databases

Tags: c#, .net, sql, datatable

I have the following code that is supposed to overwrite the local Users table with the remote one. I can see the Merge works OK, but the Update does nothing (i.e. the DataTable has new values in, but it doesn't write it to the LocalDb connection/database) - is there a simple way to do what I'm doing or make this work?

```
var RemoteUsersTable = DbRemote.ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM users");

if (RemoteUsersTable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    SqlDataAdapter LocalDataAdapter = null;
    var LocalUsersTable = DbLocal.ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM users", ref LocalDataAdapter);

    LocalUsersTable.Merge(RemoteUsersTable);
    LocalUsersTable.AcceptChanges();

    LocalDataAdapter.Update(LocalUsersTable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above code is that you have only ever setup a select command. If you are wanting to "Update" the Table then you will most likely need both an "UPDATE" & "INSERT" command for your `LocaDataAdapter`.

The `Update` method of the DataAdapter requires these commands where it is required to change/Add/Remove records in the database table.

You would normally setup a DataAdapter with specific commands.

With your command builder, you could try doing this :-

```
var RemoteUsersTable = DbRemote.ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM users");

if (RemoteUsersTable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    SqlDataAdapter LocalDataAdapter = null;
    var LocalUsersTable = DbLocal.ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM users", ref LocalDataAdapter);

    LocalUsersTable.Merge(RemoteUsersTable);
    LocalUsersTable.AcceptChanges();

    cb.GetDeleteCommand(); // WHICH EVER YOUR COMMANDBUILDER IS CALLED.
    cb.GetInsertCommand();
    cb.GetUpdateCommand();

    LocalDataAdapter.Update(LocalUsersTable);
}
```

Comment: I've not included the code behinde the DbLocal's class, which does this:
`SqlCommandBuilder CommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(refDataAdapter);

refDataAdapter.Fill(table);`
I'm right in thinking the Command Builder does that for me, right?

Comment: No, You will need three commands for the DataAdapter. an Insert command with parameters and an UPDATE command with parameters. And your Select command for grabbing Data.

Comment: RefDataAdapter.Fill(table), is using the select command, but your not telling your DataAdapter how it Insert or Update or Delete.

Comment: [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) states "you can create a SqlCommandBuilder object to automatically generate Transact-SQL statements for single-table updates if you set the SelectCommand property of the SqlDataAdapter. Then, any additional Transact-SQL statements that you do not set are generated by the SqlCommandBuilder." ... so I think you're half right - it can only update, not insert. What do you reckon?

Comment: See My EDIT. I think your missing the above part. I dont normally use a command builder, I do all of this manually.

Answer (score 0):

The call to AcceptChanges means that any changed values in LocalUsersTable are no longer marked as changed, therefore there is nothing to update.

In any case, this is a very ugly, slow and risky way to perform mass updates and is never used. Just a few of the most serious problems:

- You pull all data, from both servers to the client, before sending all of it back to one of the servers. This wastes bandwidth and processing time from all machines and is therefore extremely slow.
- You retrieve all columns from each table, which will cause the update to fail if there are schema changes.

You should use SQL statements inside a transaction to do what you want instead of using DataTables.

SQL Server has the MERGE statement that can update a target table using rows from a source query, deciding what to do (Update, Insert, Delete) using the values of each individual row. Or you can write a multiple statement script that deletes old rows and inserts the new ones inside a transaction

Comment: The AcceptChanges call makes no difference. 
Can I use a single transaction across multiple connections? If so, would really appreciate a link/example (it was what I initially wanted to do).